# White Page in Facebook Canvas App

Tags: php, facebook, canvas, facebook-apps

I developed a Facebook App using PHP. This app have worked fine last year.

Now i have migrated the App to another server. Since then, i faced a lot of problems that i overpass with some workarounds.

But, there's an error that occurs when a user views the app for the first time on apps.facebook.com/my-app using google chrome

```
Refused to display 'FACEBOOK_URL_HERE' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. about:blank:1
```

I dont know what causes this error. But if the user navigate directly to the app url on my domain. Its opens. After that, If navigate back to the apps.facebook.com/my-app its open  without error.

Comment: did you change the canvas url from the facebook app settings?

Comment: Canvas URL go to a domain. And Secure Page Tab URL go to another. Because but both go to the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers allow a web server to indicate via the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header whether pages hosted by that server should be iframeable. You need to figure out where in your application or web server this is turned on and disable it.

Comment: But, in that case. The server who is saying that cannot be displayed is the facebook.com and not my server.

Comment: Show us, then. Hard to troubleshoot when we're not allowed to see it.

Comment: Well, that's your problem. You can't present `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth` in an iframe like your code is trying to do. Facebook prevents it with X-Frame-Options.

Comment: Ok, i found the problem. I was redirecting to Login URL if i dont have  user acess token. It worked in the past. But now i must request user permission via JS SDK. Very Thanks to you!

Comment: You _must_ not use the JS (assuming “must” means “I _have_ to because there’s no other way” here) – you can also redirect to the login URL, you just have to do it within the _top window instance.